# Convergence in $L^1$ and a.e convergence implies limits are the same a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space. $f_n:X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. Show if $f_n \rightarrow g$ in $L^1$ and $f_n \rightarrow h$ almost everywhere, then $h=g$ almost everywhere. I do not know how to approach this so I will take a guess and try to show $\int|g-h|=0$. Now I have tried the following:
\begin{align}
\int|g-h|=&\int|f_n-g-f_n-h|\\
\leq& \int|f_n-g|+\int|f_n-h|
\end{align}

I know the first term goes to zero on taking the limit. Now I see, it may not be possible to use this approach, since I can't bound $|f_n-h|$ by anything nice, that will allow me to conclude the integral goes to $0$ since convergence is only almost everywhere. Have I started the problem incorrectly? If so what should I try? Also I do not understand how the result is not immediate. We know there exists a subsequence $f_{n_j} \rightarrow g$ almost everywhere, and it seems to me that I can conclude that $g=h$ almost everywhere by uniqueness of limits minus a null set. Should I try to show that uniqueness of limits implies they are equal? Any suggestions?

Comment: There is a theorem that says that if $f_n\to g$ in $L^1$, then there exists a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ such that $f_{n_k}\to g$ almost everywhere. Hence, if $f_n\to h$ a.e., then also $f_{n_k}\to h$ a.e., which implies $g = h$.

Comment: @amsmath  Would this be ok? Since there exists a subsequence such that $f_{n_k} \rightarrow g$ a.e. and $f_n \rightarrow h$ a.e. it follows that $f_n \rightarrow g$ a.e. by the uniqueness of limits so that $g=h$ a.e. But now do I have to consider where exactly $g$ and $h$ differ? Should I try and prove they differ on a null set?

Comment: "by the uniqueness of limits" - exactly! $g$ and $h$ only differ on a set of measure zero. Sure, you can go ahead and prove this.

Comment: @amsmath Also, the first approach I wrote wouldn't work because it would create a sort of "dead end" in the proof, right? There is no way I can bound the second term in the sum, so I have to look for another approach for a solution?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy can you explain?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy doesn't $f_n \rightarrow h$ a.e. and $f_{n_j} \rightarrow g$ a.e. imply that $f_n \rightarrow g$ a.e. because the pointwise limit of the subsequence must be unique a.e. since we know the sequence itself converges a.e.?